# I am making a logistic regression model. Should I test for multicollinearity in dependent features if my predicting feature in categorical?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, logistic-curve

I have a doubt, will multicollinearity affect my Logistic Regression model as my predicting(output) feature is categorical? (because correlation will make sense only for 2 continuous features and not 1 continuous and 1 categorical)

also

Does checking for multicollinearity in machine learning depend upon the type of variable that we are predicting(i.e. whether the variable is continuous or categorical)

Comment: Is the purpose of your logistic regression to understand the coefficients and to interpret your model or to simply make the best prediction possible?

Comment: To simply make the best prediction possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your updated comment, you do not need to worry about multicollinearity in this case.  Since your only goal is to make predictions based on your model, and not to interpret the coefficients, then  you can disregard any multicollinearity since it affects only the magnitude, direction, and stability of your coefficients.  But you are not concerned with interpretation of these coefficients, but rather the predictive ability of your model, so you can safely ignore multicollinearity here.  What you should be concerned about is what model has the best predictive ability when applied to out-of-sample observations (e.g. which model leads to the lowest mean squared predicted error on a validation dataset that was not used to train the model).

That being said, if your only goal is not prediction (i.e. you do want to interpret the coefficients of your model), then you will need to be concerned with multicollinearity in any regression model, regardless of whether you are predicting a continuous or categorical variable.  Also, you stated "because correlation will make sense only for 2 continuous features and not 1 continuous and 1 categorical," but this is not true.  Non-zero correlation can exist between any two non-constant variables, regardless of whether the variables are continuous or not.

Comment: @Anon, this is an elementary result in statistics, so nearly any textbook on linear models will address this.  I'd recommend Applied Linear Statistical Models, 5th by Kutner, et. al for beginners, and for the more advanced reader, texts like Linear Statistical Models, 2d. by Rencher and Schaalje; Generalized, Linear, and Mixed Models, 2d., by McCulloch, Searle, and Neuhaus, and for an advanced student, A Primer on Linear Models by John F. Monahan .